# Thunderbird crashes at startup

Tags: 18.04, email, thunderbird

Thunderbird starts and crashes immediately. I get a popup

> Mozilla Crash reporter
>   "We're Sorry"

Even uninstalling and reinstalling of Thunderbird via Terminal doesn't work. I get an error

```
Cannot find loader for bootstrap
```

The `.thunderbird` folder still exists (and is backed up). I had some Trojans, detected and quarantined.

What can I do?

In the Terminal window I read:

```
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm, line 1877: Error: Cannot find loader for bootstrap
Extension error: Error while loading 'jar:file:///usr/lib/thunderbird/extensions/messagingmenu@mozilla.com.xpi!/manifest.json' (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) resource://gre/modules/Extension.jsm:513 :: readJSON/</<@resource://gre/modules/Extension.jsm:513:20
onStopRequest@resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm:128:9

1591902885958   addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method startup on messagingmenu@mozilla.com: Error: Error while loading 'jar:file:///usr/lib/thunderbird/extensions/messagingmenu@mozilla.com.xpi!/manifest.json' (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)(resource://gre/modules/Extension.jsm:513:20) JS Stack trace: readJSON/</<@Extension.jsm:513:20
onStopRequest@NetUtil.jsm:128:9
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading packed extension from /home/ludo/.thunderbird/d6g5kzak.default/extensions/accountcolors@DW-dev.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading packed extension from /home/ludo/.thunderbird/d6g5kzak.default/extensions/duplicateContactsManager@ddvo.net.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading packed extension from /home/ludo/.thunderbird/d6g5kzak.default/extensions/tbsortfolders@xulforum.org.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading packed extension from /home/ludo/.thunderbird/d6g5kzak.default/extensions/thunderlink@mozilla.org.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading packed extension from /home/ludo/.thunderbird/d6g5kzak.default/extensions/{58D4392A-842E-11DE-B51A-C7B855D89593}.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading add-on preferences from  /home/ludo/.thunderbird/d6g5kzak.default/extensions/accountcolors@DW-dev.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Firing profile-after-change listeners for accountcolors@DW-dev
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading add-on preferences from  /home/ludo/.thunderbird/d6g5kzak.default/extensions/duplicateContactsManager@ddvo.net.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Firing profile-after-change listeners for duplicateContactsManager@ddvo.net
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading add-on preferences from  /home/ludo/.thunderbird/d6g5kzak.default/extensions/tbsortfolders@xulforum.org.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Firing profile-after-change listeners for tbsortfolders@xulforum.org
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading add-on preferences from  /home/ludo/.thunderbird/d6g5kzak.default/extensions/{58D4392A-842E-11DE-B51A-C7B855D89593}.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Firing profile-after-change listeners for {58D4392A-842E-11DE-B51A-C7B855D89593}
console.log: WebExtensions: Loading add-on preferences from  /home/ludo/.thunderbird/d6g5kzak.default/extensions/thunderlink@mozilla.org.xpi
console.log: WebExtensions: Firing profile-after-change listeners for thunderlink@mozilla.org
console.warn: Overlays.jsm: Could not resolve 1 references Array [{}]
1591902887343   tbsortfolders.folderPane    DEBUG   Init
1591902887344   tbsortfolders.folderPane    DEBUG   Add observer
console.warn: Overlays.jsm: Could not resolve 1 references Array [{}]
1591902887559   addons.xpi  WARN    Can't get modified time of /usr/lib/thunderbird/features/wetransfer@extensions.thunderbird.net
console.warn: Conversations.Conversation: "Warning: gloda query returned no messages"
console.warn: Conversations.Message: "Streaming the message because Gloda has not indexed it, this is BAD"
console.debug: "Empty aMimeLine?!!"
console.debug: "Empty aMimeLine?!!"
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 24589
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
```

Comment: Yesterday I started Thunderbird via Terminal in safe mode. It opened and is functional but in English. Before, I used the Dutch version.  When I close the program and try to open via the dock panel icon, it crashes again.

Comment: What if you launch it from Terminal, but not in safe mode ? What Thunderbird version are you using ? Do you know if it was updated recently ? Are all your addons up-to-date ?

Comment: Thank you Kulfy. I waited for the 20.04 LTS distribution (Dutch), it's installed. Use Thunderbird 68.10.0 (64-bits). The problem changed a bit: it opens nicely after startup of computer but if I 'dare' to close Thunderbird, I have to start it again via Terminal in safe mode or to reboot machine. Strange.